# memcpy "unhandled exception" "access violation reading location"

Tags: c++

I am using an array of structs to store different binary data, from different clients. While I am debugging, I can do a few iterations with success (in memcpy). But at some point the debug crashes with "unhandled exception".

```
struct Buffer {
    int size_ = 0;
    int capacity_total = 200000;
    int beg_index = 0
    int end_index = 0;
    char data_[200000];
} buffer_audio[3];

int writing_bufer(Buffer& buffers, const char *data, int nbytes) {
    if (nbytes == 0) return 0;

    int capacity = buffers.capacity_total;

    if (nbytes <= capacity - buffers.end_index)
    {
        memcpy(buffers.data_ + buffers.end_index, data, nbytes); //crashes here
        buffers.end_index += nbytes;
        if (buffers.end_index == capacity) printf("full");
    }
    else { 
        return 0; }

    return buffers.end_index;
}
```

The buffer never is full or close of that.
The full routine:

```
void buffering(const FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args) {
    Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
    HandleScope scope(isolate);

    int size = args[1]->NumberValue();
    int final_read = args[2]->NumberValue();
    int client_id = args[3]->NumberValue();
    int nbytes = args[4]->NumberValue();

    (...)
    buf = node::Buffer::Data(bufferObj);
    buffering_mem(buf,size, final_read, client_id,nbytes);


    Local<String> devolve = String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "buffering_com_sucesso");//C++--->JS
    args.GetReturnValue().Set(devolve);
}

void buffering_mem(char* chunk,int size_chunk, int close_file, int client, int total_size){

    int check_bytes = writing_bufer(buffer_audio[client], chunk, size_chunk);
    //other code}
```

Comment: If `nbytes` is the amount of bytes you want to copy using `memcpy`, the third argument of `memcpy` should be `nbytes` without the `end_idx`.

Answer (score 5):

You are copying the wrong amount in your code:

```
memcpy(buffers.data_ + buffers.end_index, data, buffers.end_index+nbytes);
```

That should be just

```
memcpy(buffers.data_ + buffers.end_index, data, nbytes);
```

Comment: You'll need to post a complete example to get better help.

Comment: `char *data_ = new char[capacity_total];` has the same behavior

Comment: I was especially wondering about the code that allocates and initializes the Buffer object.  If end_index were never initialized, we would expect it to be accidentally zero (and thus work) in the first simple cases, but might be accidentally negative when you create some Buffer object later.  Once it is negative you can get the described symptom even with the other bug fixed.  That is just a wild guess, since you didn't show that part of your code.

Comment: Yes I noted to. Big mistake...  But... Still nothing.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are saying you also fixed the bug of failing to initialize end_index and that still leaves the failures.  You added a little to the code you posted, but you fixed neither bug in that version and still don't show enough.  That new code brings up the probability of a 3rd bug (in code you didn't show) that `client` will be 3 or more, which will also cause the symptom you report.

Comment: @jdscardoso I do not know why you put tag C++ there but it is not C++ code. First of all there is a reason why incapsulation is recommended to use.

Comment: sorry @JSF.. done. 3 is just a random number. I can control the number of clients I is not higher than 3

Comment: Posted code now has that second bug fixed, but still hasn't fixed the first bug.  If there is still a third bug, I think it is in the code you haven't posted yet (such as the loop that calls buffering_mem multiple times).

Comment: @JSF As you see. The routine buffering is called multiple times by the serve. Nodejs

Answer (score 0):

With the huge help of @JSF

```
void buffering_mem(char* chunk,int size_chunk, int close_file, int client, int total_size){ 
    //old place of invocation
    if (close_file == 3) {

        fp0 = fopen("buffer_inteiro", "wb");
        fwrite(buffer_audio[client].data_, 1,total_size,fp0);
        fflush(fp0); return;
    }
    int check_bytes = writing_bufer(buffer_audio[client], chunk, size_chunk);

}
```